# Python go through User fields

Tags: python, django, loops, for-loop, celery

I have a celery task/for loop that should run through a specific list of user fields at the database but for some reason, I always get the error:

...

tasks.py

...
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you code to

```
@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(minute='*/1')), name="Check addr", ignore_result=True)
def check_addr():
    users = User.objects.all()
    for user in users:
            print(user.acc_addr)
```

Answer (score 0):

`all` is method and you should call it.

```
users = User.objects.all()
```

`all()` returns `QuerySet` which is iterable: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#all

Answer (score 0):

Replace `User.objects.all` with `User.objects.all()`